# WYSIWYG редакторы на JS

Tags: wysiwyg, html, javascript

Решил написать велосипед, а именно WYSIWYG редактор HTML на JS без использования jQuery. Когда гуглил разные редакторы и то, как их писать, видел, что везде используют для этого фрейм. А я хочу взять div с атрибутом contenteditable="true". Это возможно сделать?
И, если кто знает, вот если просто нажать на некоторый стиль и набирать им текст, то для того, чтобы его как-то форматировать в реальном времени нужно перехватывать каждый символ и выводить его в обрамляющих тегах, а потом подчищать их, что бы не было <b>h</b><b>i</b>? Или это делается легче?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я как-то помню, что пример так редактора выкладывал @RubaXa если мне память не изменяет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно без проблем использовать div с contentEditable="true". Iframe используется только для ограничения действия функции `document.execCommand`, через которую реализуется базовое редактирование.

Почитать о возможностях функции `execCommand` можно здесь: [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)

Небольшой Tutorial по теме: [Using the HTML5 attribute contenteditable to create a WYSIWYG](http://marakana.com/s/post/1096/using_the_html5_attribute_contenteditable_to_create_a_wysiwyg)

Почему все-таки лучше использовать IFrame видно на этом [примере](http://marakana.com/s/post/1096/samples/try6.htm). Редактор сделан на основе div-a. Жмем кнопку "Edit", выбираем текст за пределами редактора, и затем жмем кнопку для установки того, или иного стиля. Можно например сделать жирным текст в меню.