# Сохранить данные из div contenteditable="true"

Tags: jquery, алгоритм, html, cms

Привет, очень нравится новый атрибут `contenteditable="true"`, хочу использовать его в своей CMS. Вот смотрите: пользователь всё отредактировал как ему надо, всё красиво, а каким способом возможно сохранить этот новый текст в базу? Может кто подскажет оригинальный способ? Или просто: `jQuery('div').html()`? Может у кого есть какие наработки, сильно не пинайте за нечетки вопрос.

Comment: Тоже интересно. Думал, может html теги преобразовывать в bb коды и отправлять. Но наверно глупо. Хотел запилить визуальный редактор для пользователей :)

Comment: @ModaL: В bb коды преобразовывать конечно можно, но смысла особого нет. Если вопрос в безопасности (защите от XSS в частности), то это решается посредством фильтра запрещенных тэгов на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант `$('...').html()` достаточно оригинален. 
В качестве альтернативы можно отказаться от JQuery, и использовать например `document.getElementById('...').innerHTML`.

А вообще, если хотите сделать полноценный редактор, то лучше использовать не `div` а `iframe`. В ответе на вопрос [WYSIWYG редакторы на JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233674/html-wysiwyg-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js)  есть пояснение почему.

link text

Comment: Павел, именно поэтому и инетерсует contenteditable т.к. элементы уже "стилизованы" (<h1><h2><p><q> и т.д.) и стиль у них менять не нужно, а только контент. а всякие iframe wysiwyg слишком переполнены редактором стилей а мне нужен только контент... (никаких тегов Html,bb и тд только текст). у меня половина построено на <textarea>content content</textarea> а тут заинтересовася этим интересным свойством

Comment: кстати тот пример что в вашем ответе у меня работает корректно, никаких изменений стиля за пределами div не происходит.

Comment: @eicto: думаю зависит еще от браузера.
@Олег Б: В каком объеме давать редактирование это уже зависит от Вас. `Iframe` я посоветовал только из соображений ограничения области действия редактора.

Comment: это соображение программист может реализовать в одной проверке.

Comment: @eicto: Не спорю, но это не панацея.

Answer (score 1):

Вот знаешь, я всегда был рад когда человек пытается изобрести велосипед, но в этом случае ты уже перебрал)) самым обычным способом: `$('div').text()` и ничего человечество проще не придумало. Зачем твоему велосипеду еще колесо сверху, когда ты ездишь на двух колесах находящихся снизу? Смекаешь?