# Как получить координаты начала и конца выделенного фрагмента текста? (WYSIWYG-редактор на сайт)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Хочу сделать простенький html-редактор, чтоб мелкие ошибки проще было исправлять.

Допустим, есть textarea или div с "contenteditable". Выделяем фрагмент текста. Как вставить перед началом выделения `"<span style='color: #bbb;'>"`, а после `"</span>"`?

И вообще какие советы будут? Видел, что многие редакторы работают через iframe, зачем?

P.S. как вставить какой-либо тест в место, где сейчас находится курсор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если отвечать прямо, то вам нужно [Selection и Range](http://habrahabr.ru/post/55922/). А для простого редактора подходит именно document.execCommand. А в iframe потому, что Опера (за Хромом такого не замечал, насчёт лисы на знаю) не работает с данными с помощью этого метода в текущем фрейме.

Answer (score 2):

Все значительно проще, редактор сроится на базе функции `document.execCommand`.

Здесь уже был подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233674/html-wysiwyg-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js), в моем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233674/html-wysiwyg-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=233677#233677) на него есть ссылка на [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands) по `document.execCommand`, небольшой [tutorial](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1096/using_the_html5_attribute_contenteditable_to_create_a_wysiwyg), и описание, почему стоит редактор делать именно на базе `iframe`, а не просто `div`-a.

Comment: Насколько мне известно в execCommand есть ограниченный набор параметров и больше ничего не добавить? Ну, если вдруг захочется обернуть в экзотические теги.

Comment: @ModaL делал как-то свой редактор, без execCommand. Более детально + с [примером на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn2KX/3/) можно посмотреть [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/246867/js-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-contenteditable).